# Scala stream behaves counterintuitive

Tags: scala, stream

I am playing with Scala's streams and I'm not sure I catch the idea.
Let's consider following code

```
def fun(s: Stream[Int]): Stream[Int] = Stream.cons(s.head, fun(s.tail))
```

executing this

```
val f = fun(Stream.from(7))
f take 14 foreach println
```

results with

```
7 8 9 10 ... up to 20
```

Let's say I understand this.

Now, changing slightly code (adding 2 to head)

```
def fun(s: Stream[Int]): Stream[Int] = Stream.cons(s.head + 2, fun(s.tail))
```

results in

```
9 10 11 ... up to 22
```

Again I think I understand. Problems starts with next example (d

```
def fun(s: Stream[Int]): Stream[Int] = Stream.cons(s.head / 2, fun(s.tail))

3 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 7 8 8 9 9 10
```

This I do not get, please explain why it results this way? 
Similar, subtracting also does not behave as I expect

```
def fun(s: Stream[Int]): Stream[Int] = Stream.cons(s.head - 2, fun(s.tail))
```

Output

```
5 6 7 8 9 10 ... up to 18
```

Comment: Seems normal to me.  Why don't you try explaining what you expected vs what you got so someone can try and help you out on where the disconnect is.

Answer (score 1):

Given your "take": `7 8 9 10 ... up to 20`,

- what happens when you `+ 2` on each element?
- what happens when you `/ 2` on each element (`int` arithmetic)?
- what happens when you `- 2` on each element?

Answer (score 0):

Is it more intuitive if you think of it as mapping the `Stream`?

```
scala> val s1 = Stream.from(10)
s1: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(10, ?)

scala> val s2 = s1 map (_ * 2)
s2: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(20, ?)

scala> s2.take(5).toList
res0: List[Int] = List(20, 22, 24, 26, 28)

scala> val s3 = s1 map (_ / 2)
s3: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(5, ?)

scala> s3.take(5).toList
res1: List[Int] = List(5, 5, 6, 6, 7)

scala> val s4 = s1 map (_ - 2)
s4: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(8, ?)

scala> s4.take(5).toList
res2: List[Int] = List(8, 9, 10, 11, 12)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's try and break it down...

```
def fun(s: Stream[Int]): Stream[Int] = Stream.cons(s.head, fun(s.tail))
```

is a function that takes a `Stream` and separates its `head` and `tail`, applies itself recursively on the `tail`, and then recombines the two results with the `cons` operator.

Since the `head` is not touched during this operation, the `Stream` is rebuilt element by element as it was before.

```
val f = fun(Stream.from(7))
```

`f` it's the same as `Stream.from(7)` [i.e. an infinite sequence of increasing integers starting from 7]

Printing `f take 14` in fact shows that we have the *first 14 numbers starting from 7* [i.e. 7,8,9,...,20]

What happens next is that, while rebuilding the stream with the `cons`, each element is modified in some way

```
def fun(s: Stream[Int]): Stream[Int] = Stream.cons(s.head + 2, fun(s.tail))
```

This *adds 2* to the `head` before recombining it with the modified `tail`. The latter is modified in the same way, its first element being added to 2 and then recombined to its own `tail`, and so own.

If we assume again that `s` contains the number from 7 on, what happens looks like

```
fun(s) = cons(7 + 2, cons(8 + 2, cons(9 + 2, ... ad infinitum ... )))))
```

This is the same as adding 2 to each and every element of the stream `s`.

The code confirms that by printing "9 to 22", which is exactly "7 to 20" with 2 added to every element.

The others examples are analogous:

- the stream with each element *divided by 2* (and rounded to the floor
  integer value, since the `Stream` is typed with `Int` values)
- the stream where each element is *decremented by 2*